# How to charge lithium ion battery in series and parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, lithium-ion

I want to use TP4056 in my solar power bank project to charge a lithium-ion battery (3.7 V, 2000mAh each one), but I don't know how to use it when I want to charge more than one battery.

Is those schematics correct?

**parallel batteries**

[image]

**series batteries**

[image]

Comment: Please read the datasheet for TP4056, first line. You can’t use it for series connected batteries.

Comment: I have found this and i think is true [link of circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKqYU.png) ,but why i can't use just one power supply for the three tp4056?  , I read that because they have a common ground ,I did not understand well, Can you explain more @winny

Comment: Do you have two floating power supplies for the two top batteries as per the schematic?

Comment: In a project, i will use as power supply a phone charger and in another a solar cell. but why i need to use three power supply to charge the three series batteries.

Comment: Galvanic separation since the TP4056 isn’t isolated. Draw a circuit diagram with all your local grounds and you will see.

Comment: [link of circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0PYp.png) , what is the problem? Please Can you explain to me in detail, Because I did not understand well.

Comment: I just told you. Have you tried to do any research on the subject? Simulated the circuit? Built it step by step and noticed at what point it goes up in flames?

Comment: Yes i have research on this subject and i found that i need to put a power supply for each TP4056 because they have a common ground, but I haven't understood well, I'm new in that. I think is the same thing [Link of the two examples](https://image.ibb.co/ne8B4z/61c_Az9o_Xgp_L_SL1000.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The series circuit is not correct as it does not define each battery voltage. You would need a balancer circuit for serial charging these batteries.

Comment: Infact not ballanced voltage involves damage to the cells

Answer (score 0):

You should use TP4056 module for each battery(in your case you have to use 3 TP4056 module). Connect all the input power supply of TP4056 module in parallel and connect individual battery to each module.

Comment: He needs floating power supplies for the top two for that.